# LXC - Failed to create macvlan interface - Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, lxd, openvz, macvlan

I am having problem to create a LXC container over OpenVZ server, I am getting the error bellow when lxc try to create an interface. I am not sure if OpenVZ permit this kind of configuration, it is my first time trying. I have looking for some solution on the internet, but I didn't find anything to solve my problem. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

root@websrv:~# lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 ubuntu
Creating ubuntu
Starting ubuntu
Error: Failed to run: /usr/lib/lxd/lxd forkstart ubuntu /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/ubuntu/lxc.conf:
Try `lxc info --show-log local:ubuntu` for more info
root@websrv:~# lxc info --show-log local:ubuntu
Name: ubuntu
Remote: unix://
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2020/06/01 20:48 UTC
Status: Stopped
Type: persistent
Profiles: default

Log:

lxc ubuntu 20200601204903.730 ERROR    network - network.c:instantiate_macvlan:234 - Operation not permitted - Failed to create macvlan interface "mcHNUAG7" on "venet0"
lxc ubuntu 20200601204903.730 ERROR    network - network.c:lxc_create_network_priv:2457 - Failed to create network device
lxc ubuntu 20200601204903.730 ERROR    start - start.c:lxc_spawn:1626 - Failed to create the network
lxc ubuntu 20200601204903.730 ERROR    start - start.c:__lxc_start:1939 - Failed to spawn container "ubuntu"
lxc ubuntu 20200601204903.733 ERROR    lxccontainer - lxccontainer.c:wait_on_daemonized_start:842 - Received container state "STOPPING" instead of "RUNNING"
lxc 20200601204903.765 WARN     commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_recv:132 - Connection reset by peer - Failed to receive response for command "get_state"

Answer (score 0):

I just found that is better have KVM VPS if you are planning to use LXC or Docker. OpenVZ have few limitation.